# Conditional coloring with <apex:EnhancedList> property - is this possible?

Tags: apex, visualforce

One can conditionally colour particular columns and rows within a page block table.

One of the best examples of this can be seen from the [Visualforce Development Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/visualforce-development-cookbook) or the 2nd edition [here](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/visualforce-development-cookbook-second-edition).

[image]

```
<apex:column style="color: {!IF(AND(NOT(ISNULL(campaign.ActualCost)), campaign.ActualCost<=campaign.BudgetedCost), "lawngreen", "red")}" value="{!campaign.ActualCost}"/>
```

However, is it possible to do conditional colouring on an enhancedList property?

```
<apex:enhancedList type="Your_Custom_Object__c" height="500" rowsPerPage="25" customizable="true" />
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm) on the possible attributes for this, it would seem that this isn't feasible? Does this mean that I would have to create another page block table section with a child page block table?

Comment: Maybe with Javascript...

Comment: You could, alternatively, attempt to add an icon (as a formula field) to the enhancedList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really interested to do it. You can do it by Javascript (Jquery) using `<apex:enahncedList/>`

- Download and add the jquery to page.

  - Include jquery on page by `<apex:includeScript/>`
- Add the `<apex:enhancedList/>` for Campaign

Add the snippet in the last:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {    
                window.setTimeout(colorIt,2000);
        });

        function colorIt()
        {
            var theDiv = $("div[class$='col-ActualCost']");
            if(theDiv) {
                theDiv.each(function() {
                    var dollor = $(this).html();
                    if(dollor != undefined && dollor != '' && dollor != null) {
                        var removeDollar = dollor.replace('$','');
                        removeDollar = removeDollar.replace(/,/g,'');
                        var num = parseFloat(removeDollar);
                        if(num > 50000) {
                            $(this).css('color','orange');
                        }
                        else if(num > 25000) {
                            $(this).css('color','crimson');
                        }
                        else if(num > 20000) {
                            $(this).css('color','green');
                        }
                        else if(num > 9000) {
                            $(this).css('color','darkgoldenrod ');
                        }
                    }
               });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Numbers 50000, 10000 etc. are the currency shown in each row in column Actual Cost.

[image]